# Implementing deep ensemble learning in Tensorflow for uncertainty estimation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

I am trying to implement deep ensemble model in Tensorflow. Specifically, I am trying to reproduce the results discussed in the paper "Simple and Scalable Predictive Uncertainty Estimation using Deep Ensembles, [Balaji Lakshminarayanan et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01474)". The authors state that an ensemble of neural networks can be used to estimate prediction uncertainty. For regression problems, the authors instruct to output two values in the final layer corresponding to mean prediction and variance. The cost function to be minimized is then the negative log-likelihood. I have implemented this as follows,

```
def base_model():
        # Base model upon which ensembles will be built
        inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
        x = Dense(50, activation='relu')(inputs)
        x = Dense(50, activation='relu')(x)
        # Note two outputs for the final layer corresponding to mean and variance
        x = Dense(2, activation=None)(x)

        model = keras.Model(inputs, dist)
        model.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.lr), loss=NLL)
        return model

def NLL(ytrue, ypred):
        # Negative log-likelihood activation function
        # variance is sotfmax of the NN output so that it is always positive number
        var = tf.math.log(1.0+tf.math.exp(ypred[...,1:2])) + 1e-6
        # Negative log-likelihood formula
        NLL = tf.math.log(var)*0.5 + 0.5*tf.math.divide(tf.math.square(ytrue-ypred[...,0:1]),var)
        return NLL

def train(self, xtrain, ytrain, batch, epochs, validation_data=None):
        h = []
        models = []
        # Train 10 models
        for i in range(10):
            # Get model
            models.append(base_model())
            # Train model
            h1=models[i].fit(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size=batch, validation_data=validation_data, epochs=epochs)
            h.append(h1)
        return h, models
```

Now according to the above-quoted paper, the ensemble of neural network can be used to estimate variance. I trained an ensemble consisting of 10 neural networks and tried to reproduce Figure 1 (last panel) in the paper which is the following

[image]

In this figure red dots are the training examples and grey bands are the predicted mean and 3 standard deviations. The important thing to note is that the variance is high in regions where there are no training examples. However, with my implementation, the variance does not show such a trend (example figure below). I have tried various configurations but can't reproduce the results of the paper. I have however found an article in [medium](https://medium.com/@albertoarrigoni/paper-review-code-deep-ensembles-nips-2017-c5859070b8ce) where an implementation for the same paper has been done but that implementation is significantly different and more complex than mine.

I am wondering if there is some logical mistake in my implementation?

[image]

Comment: Yes this does not really work and I am not sure why, but I implemented a deep ensemble in another way in my library and it works flawlessly: https://github.com/mvaldenegro/keras-uncertainty/blob/master/examples/regression_deep-ensemble.py

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks for sharing your library. I tried running the example regression script in your library but still couldn't get the expected high variance in regions where there are no training examples. The behaviour of your library is more like the result from my code attached in the question. Am I missing something? Do I have to change some parameters?

Comment: This is what I get https://github.com/mvaldenegro/keras-uncertainty/blob/master/examples/deepensemble-x-pow-3.png It clearly shows increasing epistemic uncertainty outside of the training set. To enhance the result increase the number of ensemble members.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy While the epistemic uncertainty grows outside the training set, the increase is not as dramatic as shown in the paper. I can also reproduce such a large increase using the code in the medium article. This large increase is important to judge the model confidence.

Comment: I also tried using 20 ensemble members but didn't see a significant difference in the results.